# How to add a 2D matrix to another 3D matrix in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, addition

I have an 3D matrix `a`,like this:

```
a=np.array([[[1,2],[2,3]],[[3,4],[4,5]]])
[
 [[1 2],[2 3]]
 [[3 4],[4 5]]
]
a.shape
(2, 2, 2)
```

Now, I want to add another element, like `[[5,6],[6,7]]` to this array.
So, new array will be:

```
[
 [[1, 2],[2, 3]]
 [[3, 4],[4, 5]]
 [[5, 6],[6, 7]]
]
a.shape
(3, 2, 2)
```

What is the best way to do this?
( I'm working with big datasets so I need the best way)

Comment: How do you want to add? Expected o/p?

Comment: @Divakar : add an element to the first dimension. I explained more in question body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`np.vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) to vertically stack after extending the second array to `3D` by adding a new axis as its first axis with `None/np.newaxis`, like so -

```
np.vstack((a,b[None]))
```

Sample run -

```
In [403]: a
Out[403]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [2, 3]],

       [[3, 4],
        [4, 5]]])

In [404]: b
Out[404]: 
array([[5, 6],
       [6, 7]])

In [405]: np.vstack((a,b[None]))
Out[405]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [2, 3]],

       [[3, 4],
        [4, 5]],

       [[5, 6],
        [6, 7]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.append` to append to matrixes:

```
a = np.array([[[1,2],[2,3]],[[3,4],[4,5]]])
a = np.append(a, [[[5,6],[6,7]]], axis=0)
```

Note that I had to add an extra set of brackets around the second part, in order for the dimensions to be correct. Also, you must use an `axis` or it will all be flattened to a linear array.

Answer (score 1):

Try numpy.append

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[[1,2],[2,3]],[[3,4],[4,5]]])
b=np.array([[3,4],[4,5]])
np.append(a,[b[:,:]],axis=0)
```